# Refactoring method with few boolean parameters

Tags: java, refactoring

There is a good approach to refactoring. For example, we have this method with flag:

```
public void process(boolean hasLicense){
        if (hasLicense){
            System.out.println("has");
        }else {
            System.out.println("has not");
        }
    }
```

We can split it into two methods:

```
public void processWithLicense() {
    System.out.println("has");
}

public void processWithoutLicense() {
    System.out.println("has not");
}
```

But what about this type of method?

```
public void process(boolean hasLicense, boolean isAdmin) {
        if (hasLicense && isAdmin) {
            System.out.println("success");
        }
        
        System.out.println("some code");
        
        if (isAdmin){
            System.out.println("add grants");
        }

        System.out.println("10 lines code");
        
        if (isAdmin && !hasLicense){
            System.out.println("something");
        }
    }
```

How can I refactor this method and remove boolean parameters?

Comment: What goal do you want to achieve by removing the parameters? How is the code meant to get to the information, if they are not parameters?

Comment: Why do you want to refactor like this? What benefits we are getting out of it? Don't understand the purpose of doing so. can you please edit your question with the intent behind it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as there is no specific programming problem and more of a code review one - this would most likely be an opinion-based discussion. I think https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this kind of question.

Comment: @ Joachim Sauer I have a method with 4 boolean parameters and 11 other parameters. I want to refactor this bullshit

Comment: It seems to me that your example is oversimplified and there are way bigger design problems in your code.

Comment: There is a recommendation made in *Effective Java* (in Item 51 in 3rd Ed) to use two-element enums instead of boolean parameters. There are various reasons, but they include things like: enum values "HAS_LICENSE", "NO_LICENSE" are more descriptive at the call site; specifically-typed enums mean you can't accidentally swap parameters; you can add more values at a later date.

Comment: @ Amongalen yes, you are right. 600 lines code in one method and 15 parameters.

Comment: @PavelPetrashov you could refactor this into a parameter object. Obviously you don't simply want to create a class with a 15-param constructor instead, so you might want to create some sub messages to reflect the logical grouping of the parameters (e.g. if two adjacent parameters are "x" and "y" coordinates, then these could be grouped into a point class).

Comment: @Andy Turner It is not my code. Previous "developer"  passed unrelated parameters to the method. It is spaghetti code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I refactor this method and remove boolean parameters?

The thing about refactoring is that the decision strongly depends on what you're trying to do, and what the *actual* code look like: I can make suggestions, but these may or may not be suitable.

Something you could use here is the [Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_pattern): you could define an interface something like:

```
interface Template {
  void part1();
  void part2();
  void part3();
}
```

and then refactor your method to look like:

```
public void process(Template template) {
    template.part1();
    
    System.out.println("some code");
    
    template.part2();

    System.out.println("10 lines code");
    
    template.part3();
}
```

and then pass in implementations of that interface for (admin/non-admin) x (license/no license).

Obviously this gets combinatorially large if you need to represent all of the possibilities, so you might not want to do this.

---

If the objection is to passing *booleans*, you could use another type. *Effective Java* makes the recommendation to pass two-element enums instead of booleans, for a number of reasons, including:

- Being more descriptive: call sites are self-documenting where a literal value is used
- Easier to add more options in the future
- Being harder to get the order wrong, because the types of adjacent parameters are different

```
enum AdminState { IS_ADMIN, NOT_ADMIN }
enum LicenceState { HAS_LICENCE, NO_LICENCE }

public void process(AdminState adminState, LicenceState licenceState) {
    if (licenceState == HAS_LICENCE && adminState == IS_ADMIN) {
        System.out.println("success");
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, if it is specifically *passing many arguments* that you want to avoid, you could create a class to hold the many arguments:

```
class ProcessArgs {
  boolean isAdmin() { ... }
  boolean hasLicense() { ... }
}
```

and then pass that in:

```
public void process(ProcessArgs args) {
    if (args.hasLicense() && args.isAdmin()) {
        System.out.println("success");
    }
    // ...
}
```

This brings up the question of how an instance of `ProcessArgs` would be initialized: if you've simply got a constructor that takes the 2 booleans, it doesn't really help much in the goal of "not passing booleans", because you've just moved 2 booleans from a method to a constructor.

However, it does have the advantage of allowing you to pass the same set of arguments in multiple places, without worrying about things like transposing arguments.